# Part of the screen flashes black when using photoshop in MBP retina

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, macbook-pro

I have a mid 2014 Mac Book Pro retina, and I use the latest version of Photoshop CC. When I'm working on something, like moving the cursor around, clicking and dragging a text element, etc., the right half of the screen goes black instantaneously, and then comes back. It happens only in photoshop, and my screen is otherwise fine. How can I diagnose the problem?

Here are some specs:

- OS X Yosemite `10.10.3`
- 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem goes away with the update to Photoshop CC 2015.